# Fox Float RP2 shock tuning (rebound, compression/velocity, boost valve)

Tags: maintenance, shocks

Does anyone have an experience with Fox Float RP2 tuning? I bought a used Giant Reign 2 2011 and it came with "L" - I guess that means "low" - "velocity tune" (earlier called compression tune). The velocity tune is supposed to correspond to the level of ProPedal. So that seems that the Reign has the smallest ProPedal setting from factory. I think I could use a greater level of ProPedal (2 or 3). I just sent the shock for an annual maintenance. Is it possible to change the velocity tune? Do you think it is a good idea. The guy from maintenance company told me it is not a good idea to change velocity tune on a particular bike because it could collide with a frame geometry.

Comment: Maybe try their support centre with an email.

Answer (score 2):

The guy from the "maintenance" company is kinda right, kinda not. Talking to an expert (like PUSH) would be where to go to find out what changes work with your particular bike.